# Argument passed to ivXml::setNodeTree()

Tags: php, gallery

I have this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: User Error
>   Message: Argument passed to ivXml::setNodeTree() must be an instance of ivXmlNode
>   Filename: /imagevue/include/ivXml.class.php
>   Line Number: 140

I read a lot of post about this problem, but nothing helped me. I tried to delete file folders.xml, tried to replace folderdata.xml with original one. But nothing helped.

Comment: What's unclear about the message? You are trying to call `ivXml::setNodeTree()` with an invalid argument.

Comment: By passing the correct argument. What does your *relevant* code look like?

Comment: I have gallery Imagevue. And this error of this gallery. So i didnt write this code. I just downloaded this gallery and recieved an error.

Comment: Never just use code of which you don't understand its workings. If it doesn't introduce vulnerabilities it will make it very very hard to debug.

Comment: my Bosss gave me site for administration. So...i dont have a choice.I have to fix it...soo...